# How can I remotely watch logs on Win2003 servers?

Tags: windows, logging, remote-access, application-server

(Briefly, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83741) but for Windows servers.)

I have several Win2003 servers running custom application services (C/C++, not Java) that write text-based logs in a custom format.

```
[2009-07-17 12:34:56.7890]\t  INFO\t<ThreadID>\tLog message...
[2009-07-17 12:34:56.7890]\t *WARN\t<ThreadID>\tLog message...
[2009-07-17 12:34:56.7890]\t**ERR \t<ThreadID>\tLog message...
```

I would like to have a way to easily and efficiently (over a not-very-fast VPN) "watch" these logs for lines that match a pattern (like `tail -f |grep -E` on linux).  Ideally the output would need to be aggregated, not one window/shell per file or per server, and a Windows application would be best, so that I can put it in front of people who are command-line-phobic.

Any recommendations?

edit: fixed link

Comment: You may wish to ask this question on serverfault.com, the sister site, if you don't get the replies you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)

Comment: I wish it didn't put each file in a separate tab, but it's workable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

splunk from [www.splunk.com](http://www.splunk.com) is the way to go. It is free & does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Yeah, I intended to mention that.  I saw it on the question I linked, but I'm going to have a hard time getting approval for anything installed on a server, and I was hoping for a free solution.  (500MB/day is not even enough for one server.)