# single log file for multiple server instances of a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have deployed a ruby on rails app on multiple instances of production server, now there are two separate log file are being created for different instances. My question is how I can make a single log file for both the instances?

Comment: Please someone help as early as possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83741/best-way-to-aggregate-multiple-log-files-from-several-servers

Comment: thanks  Max Williams