# How to collect access logs from different nodes?

Tags: java, logging, cluster-computing, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a lot of nodes (about 18) on Production, and it is necessary to find out if the specific user made requests from the mobile app (access logs have this info).

SAP Hybris doesn't store such info in the database, so it is necessary to search the logs. Each node has a file like `log/tomcat/access.2018-11-22.log`. It would be unreasonable to check each file manually.

Maybe there is a well-known solution for the situations like this?

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83741/best-way-to-aggregate-multiple-log-files-from-several-servers

Answer (score 2):

There are 3rd party solutions such as Splunk and ELK which will collect the data from log files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [it](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack)

Its a ELK stack, very common and easy to use in production

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a tool then i would recommend to use Splunk else you can log request in database as per the requirements.

If you can share the requirements in detail then i am happy to help you providing better solution.

Answer (score 0):

We are developing micro service projects and have about 20 services. All the services connect to **ELK(Elastic search,Logstash,Kibana)**. We are viewing all the log though Kibana.It is very easy make queries to search what we want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, Hybris Help also has a guide on how to setup B2C Accelerator in a Docker Container with Centralized Logging: https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/af36215ea1e34c22a1e3cbb2d550f733.html

Answer (score 0):

Use ELK - elasticsearch logstash and kibana stack with filebeat.
Filebeat -will share the log file content with logstash
Logstash-will scan, filter and share the needed content to elastic search
Elasticsearch- will work as a db, store the content from logstash in json format as documents.
Kibana- with kibana you can search the required info. Also you can plot graphs and other visuals with the relevant data.