# Best Way to Aggregate Log Files from Multiple Remote Windows Servers

Tags: c#, powershell, logging, windows-services, wmi

I have a Windows Desktop application written in C# that takes information from Windows services, web services, databases and other components running on various remote Windows servers for specific stages in a process.  Currently, the application reads information from a shared database to get an indication of when to move on to the next step in a process, but the details and verbose information that each component outputs to its logs is not captured in the shared database, and I want to capture this log information in a "master process steps detail" type list that the Windows Desktop application can display to users.

Is there a best method or practice for capturing logs in various formats from multiple Windows servers?

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they seem to be based more in the Linux or other non-Windows servers:
[Best way to aggregate multiple log files from several servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83741/best-way-to-aggregate-multiple-log-files-from-several-servers)

I was told that perhaps WMI might be able to help somehow, but would like confirmation.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several sources outside of StackOverflow have recommended that I look into using [Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/products/), so I'm moving forward with that for now.